# Minecraft getting low frames on dedicated GPU despite GPU usage being low

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, graphics, performance, minecraft

First, some system specifications:

- Running an i5-11400H for a processor
- Using an Nvidia RTX 3050 ti for a graphics card

I've already forced the game to use the graphics card, and the performance is actually lower in general than on integrated graphics (if we exclude shaders).

The FPS can drop to a mere ~10fps in some areas, pictured in a screenshot seen at the base of this post.

GPU utilization (mentioned in Nvidia X Server Settings) showed up at around 20% all the time, and there's practically 0 difference between shaders and not using shaders while on GPU.

What's limiting the framerate here? I'm on a server too, so it's not like the CPU heavy stuff is done locally.

Any tips on how to increase performance, if even marginally?

The graphics driver version (latest for this machine, apparently) as well as a few other details can be spotted in the screenshot attached to the post. I'm unsure what details exactly would be useful, so ask away for other details!

[image]

Since someone asked for it, the debug pie chart:

[image]

Comment: I see 20.03 in the original question title so I have taken the liberty (along with some editing of the question in general) of adding Focal Fossa to the tags...

Comment: Please show the Minecraft debug pie chart. Since you say the dedicated GPU is slower, have you tried turning off / making lazy the animated textures?

Comment: @Daniel T It's mostly animated models, don't have the option to turn them off, haven't seen one to make them lazy either. I'll get the pie chart in a bit and edit it into the post.

Comment: If it's models, then you might be CPU bound by your driver. Try https://modrinth.com/mod/entityculling and https://modrinth.com/mod/immediatelyfast

Comment: The top level of the pie chart isn't very specific. You could also try disabling mipmap levels

Comment: @DanielT mipmap levels didn't affect it, entity culling mod didn't help either, and the last one you linked doesn't have a forge 1.18.2 version

Comment: From the GPU underutilization, and the problem being near an area with machines, the lag must be from the CPU being too slow to render those machines. I found a forge version at https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/immediatelyfast-reforged/files/all?page=1&pageSize=20&version=1.18.2 . The other thing I do with my game is replace the JVM with https://www.graalvm.org/downloads/ but that's a bit more complicated

Comment: Can Minecraft only use one core at a time? That's the only way I can think of that could make the CPU be the limit, as it's only about 12% in use while I'm in game. Performance with both the mod and the replaced JVM is about 2-3 frames better.

Comment: Most games, especially OpenGL ones are single-threaded. Aside from overclocking, you are near machines so basically indoors so you can lower render distance. You could also [edit] the question by the following: 1. Run `jps` and find the Minecraft process. 2. Run `jstack <pid>` 10 times 3. Look for the Render Thread 4. Tell us which mod or methods it seems to be spending the most time in

Comment: There seems to only be one render thread? Aside from "Chunk Render Task Executor"s, I can only find one "Render thread", #1, using grep to narrow down the results of course

Comment: Yes, there is only one render thread. By running `jstack` 10 times, we can somewhat get a sense of where that thread is spending its time

Comment: Block entity render dispatcher seems to appear most often

Comment: Please say which block entity. I'm sure it was the tinkers' construct channel running along the left side of the road. They are known to be laggy https://forums.technicpack.net/topic/59276-casting-channel-not-working/?do=findComment&comment=514874